# Query Lucene on Kibana Discover not working as intended?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, logstash, kibana

I'm trying to search servers names on "host" attribut of my logstash index.

I'm searching on the Discover tab in Kibana.

When I tape **sl00pm** in the search bar I got :

> **No results found**

But when I add asterisk(*) and search for **sl00pm*** I got this :

> host:**sl00pm.soo85**.poly-vale.intra date:2019-03-20 15:23:10,591

I don't understand why.

But when I do the same manip for another server name **slzq85** I got this :

> host:**slzq85**.soo85.poly-vale.intra date:21/Mar/2019:09:24:56 +0100

And this is what I'm expecting.

Here is the definition of my Index on LogStash :

```
{
 "logstash-2019.03.20": {
  "aliases": {},
  "mappings": {
   "apache-access": {
    "_all": {
     "enabled": true,
     "norms": false
    },
    "dynamic_templates": [
     {
      "message_field": {
       "match": "message",
       "match_mapping_type": "string",
       "mapping": {
        "index": "analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "type": "string"
       }
      }
     },
     {
      "string_fields": {
       "match": "*",
       "match_mapping_type": "string",
       "mapping": {
        "fields": {
         "raw": {
          "ignore_above": 256,
          "index": "not_analyzed",
          "type": "string"
         }
        },
        "index": "analyzed",
        "omit_norms": true,
        "type": "string"
       }
      }
     }
    ],
    "properties": {
     "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
     },
     "@version": {
      "type": "keyword"
     },
     "date": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false,
      "fields": {
       "raw": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
       }
      }
     },
     "host": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false,
      "fields": {
       "raw": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
       }
      }
     }
    }
   },
  },
  "settings": {
   "index": {
    "refresh_interval": "5s",
    "number_of_shards": "5",
    "provided_name": "logstash-2019.03.20",
    "creation_date": "1553036402235",
    "number_of_replicas": "1",
    "uuid": "mCSFLYGETPm6qbgOwShHog",
    "version": {
     "created": "5060399"
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

And the version :

```
version": {
 "number": "5.6.3",
 "lucene_version": "6.6.1"
},
```

Could you please tell me why my results aren't good?

I want to add that I'm using mapping types and having the same attribute in different mapping types of my Index but with the same definition as above

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that behavior is where the analyzer breaks words.  The standard analyzer breaks words according to the rules laid out in [UAX #29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries). Rules WB6 and WB11, in particular, are the ones to take note of here.

Basically, it will not break on a letters with a '.' in the middle (ex: "ab.cd"), or on numbers with a '.' in the middle (ex: "12.34"), but it will break on numbers and letters separated by a '.' (ex: "12.cd").

So in your index, "sl00pm.soo85" is indexed as a single token, but "slzq85.soo85" is separated into two tokens: "slz85" and "soo85".

The standard analyzer is designed to work best on text. Words and sentences. For an identifier like you are looking at, you might try a different analyzer, perhaps [PatternAnalyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
your explanation is so much reasonable. this helps me a lot.

Comment: I may have another question about the Pattern Analyser. as I am working on production environment. I wanted to know if there are any risks to use this Analyser.